# Using global variables in a function loaded from a script file

Tags: matlab, gnu, octave

So I got this function:

```
function M = getA(X)
global h;
QPL96 =  h;
M = QPL96;
endfunction
```

Now:

```
octave:115> h
h =  0.10000
octave:116> getA(X)
ans = [](0x0)
```

Isn't that strange?
Works as long as there isn't an expression involving h. Otherwise returns that garbage.
Why can't I do this? Must I work around it by making h an argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to declare `h` as global everywhere you want to use the "global" `h`, and that includes your main body. So type `global h` at the prompt and you'll be fine. See the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Global-Variables.html). The following works fine for me:

```
octave> function M = getA(X)
> global h;
> M = h;
> endfunction
octave> h = 0.01
h =  0.0010000
octave> getA
ans = [](0x0)
octave> global h
octave> h
h = [](0x0)
octave> h = 0.01
h =  0.010000
octave> h
h =  0.010000
octave> getA
ans =  0.010000
```

But really, you shouldn't use global variables, that's really bad practice. Pass the variable as argument. If you find yourself passing the same group of variables, pass a struct, but still don't use global variables.

**EDIT:** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414283) is the same question.